# How to stop other Thread execution immediately?

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to kill a thread immediately from another thread in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530744/how-to-kill-a-thread-immediately-from-another-thread-in-java)
>   [How to properly stop the Thread in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

I need a way to stop another Thread execution ass needed just on time, I mean without any delay, for example while the user clicks a button, the Thread stops it's execution **immediately** (not important what was doing).

I think a way is to submit that Runnable class via an `ExecutorService` and cancel the returned Future while needed. at the other side I must check `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()` and if that was true the thread returns.

But it has a problem, it doesn't work immediately. any better idea?

Comment: There's really no such thing as immidietly when it comes to threads as you are dependant on the schedueler.

Comment: Threads should cooperate with their own termination. It is the clean way to do things. Killing a non-cooperating thread can lead to strange problems (which is why stop() was deprecated).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530744/how-to-kill-a-thread-immediately-from-another-thread-in-java?rq=1, and many others